# How to use grouping, aggregate, transformation and filtering on stream

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream, reduce, flatmap

assume stream of txn, where each txn has following fields

{ date, amt, name, merchant }
given txn stream
     group by yyyy-mm // fold 1
      within group(yyyy-mm); Map to new object Expense(income, spent)
            if amount > 0 then income+=amt // conditional fold 2.a
            if amount < 0 then spent+=amt // conditional fold 2.b

am wondering what are approach(es) to achieve above in java. 
Tried below, it falls way short

```
    txns
                .stream()
                .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Txn::getYearMonth, 
                        Collectors.mapping(
                            getExpense,
                            Collectors.toList())));
```

getexpense is function map I wrote to transform Txn to Expense object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are stuck on the aggregate step.  The code you posted will result in this:

```
Map<YearMonth, List<Expense>>
```

While I'm guessing you want:

```
Map<YearMonth, Expense>  // transactions aggregated into a single Expense
```

In order to do this you need to create a collector that can aggregate `Expense` objects.

It would look like this:

```
Collector.of(
  Expense::new,
  (Expense e, Transaction t) -> e.add(t),
  (e1, e2) -> new Expense(e1, e2)
);
```

Your expense class will need:

1. a public empty constructor
2. a constructor that takes 2 expenses and creates a new aggregated expense
3. an `add` method that adds a `Transaction` to an `Expense`

Something like this:

```
public class Expense {
  private double income;
  private double spent;

  public Expense() {
  }

  public Expense(Expense e1, Expense e2) {
    this.income = e1.income + e2.income;
    this.spent = e1.spent + e2.spent;
  }

  public void add(Transaction t) {
    this.income += t.getAmount() > 0 ? t.getAmount() : 0;
    this.spent += t.getAmount() < 0 ? t.getAmount() : 0;
  }
}
```

You can then use this `Collector` in the groupingBy:

```
groupingBy(Txn::getYearMonth, myCollector)
```

And the result will be aggregated expenses in a single `Expense` object.

**Update**

So like this:

```
Collector<Transaction, Expense, Expense> c = Collector.of(
  Expense::new,
  (Expense e, Transaction t) -> e.add(t),
  (e1, e2) -> new Expense(e1, e2)
);

Map<YearMonth, Expense> collect = txns.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Transaction::getYearMonth, c));
```

Comment: culd u help me define myCollector

Comment: I suppose, the amount of the transaction should be added to `income` or `spent` rather than overwriting it…

Comment: Yeah, seems I missed that, updating it

Comment: @john16384 above code does not compile, unless I change to belowCollector.of(
  Expense::new,
  (Expense e, Transaction t) -> e.add(t),
  (e1, e2) -> new Expense(e1, e2)
);

Comment: Error below on line              
The method mapping(Function<? super T,? extends U>, Collector<? super U,A,R>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments (Function<Txn,Expense>, Collector<Txn,Expense,Expense>) TxnsController.java /deepak/src/main/java/com/example